# 'unknown mount option' when podman-compose

Tags: docker-compose, podman, podman-compose

I am using `podman-compose` instead of `docker-compose`.

My `docker-compose.yml` had no problems when using `docker-compose`, but it makes an error with `podman-compose`.

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  mysql:
    image: docker.io/mysql
    container_name: mysql
    hostname: mysql
    volumes:
      - D:\mysql\test\data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "password"
      MYSQL_TCP_PORT: 8026
    ports:
      - "8026:8026"
```

When `podman-compose up`:

```
['podman', '--version', '']
using podman version: 4.3.1
** excluding:  set()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ymy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\ymy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\ymy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\podman-compose.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\ymy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\podman_compose.py", line 1775, in main
    podman_compose.run()
  File "C:\Users\ymy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\podman_compose.py", line 1024, in run
    cmd(self, args)
  File "C:\Users\ymy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\podman_compose.py", line 1248, in wrapped
    return func(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\ymy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\podman_compose.py", line 1415, in compose_up
    podman_args = container_to_args(compose, cnt, detached=args.detach)
  File "C:\Users\ymy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\podman_compose.py", line 644, in container_to_args
    podman_args.extend(get_mount_args(compose, cnt, volume))
  File "C:\Users\ymy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\podman_compose.py", line 399, in get_mount_args
    if is_str(volume): volume = parse_short_mount(volume, basedir)
  File "C:\Users\ymy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\podman_compose.py", line 129, in parse_short_mount
    raise ValueError("unknown mount option "+opt)
ValueError: unknown mount option /var/lib/mysql
```

I think that it read colon(`:`) at Windows drive(`D:`) as delimeter so the last field `/var/lib/mysql` is read as options like `ro`, `rw`. But I don't know how I can solve this.

Answer (score 2):

This page (https://github.com/containers/podman/blob/main/docs/tutorials/podman-for-windows.md) gives a definition for 'Unixy' Windows paths.  my references then went from:
d:/path
to
/d/path
Have a look and let us know how you get on